# How do I remove "TAG" field from class using ProGuard?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm trying to get my android ProGuard configuration working properly. So far I'm pretty happy with the results but there is one thing that's really bugging me; even if it's not that big of a deal.

I copied the `proguard-android-optimize.txt` file and modified that to remove my logging using the following

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.my.package.Logger { *; }
```

I know `*;` is "bad" but it's my own logging class so it doesn't matter if things like `wait` are removed. The above works great to remove all my logging but I'm trying to remove the remaining `TAG` variables from all my classes. The `TAG` variables are defined like this:

```
private static final String TAG = thisClass.class.getSimpleName();
```

I've tried to remove them with configurations like these

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.my.package.** { static final *** TAG; }
-assumenosideeffects class com.my.package.** { static final java.lang.String TAG; }
-assumenosideeffects class com.my.package.thisClass { static final java.lang.String TAG; }
```

I've also tried to do it by attempting to remove all calls to `getSimpleName` but that didn't work either. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to remove these `TAG` fields that are no longer used?

**Some additional information**: The calls to the logger are not concatinating any string, that is to say the log messages and TAGs are used as such

```
com.my.package.Logger.log(TAG, "debug message");
//NOT log(TAG + "debug message");
```

After ProGuard is run, the resulting `TAG` field is technically no longer used but ProGuard optimizes it to this

```
public void method()
{
    String _tmp = a; //was Logger.log(TAG, "test");
    //_tmp is never used anywhere else in this method
}

private static final String a = com/my/package/thisClass/getSimpleName();
```

Comment: I assume you also tried adding `private` to the field specifications in your above attempts, right?  (Not saying it's necessary -- I don't know, just wondering if you tried it.)

Comment: @Turix Yep, sure did. Also, just so you know (since you said you're not sure) the ProGuard docs on [class_specification](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classspecification) say that specifying private/public/protected isn't necessary unless you want to restrict your rule further.

Comment: sorry, it was worth a shot. It's too bad ProGuard doesn't have a `dontkeep` directive; specifying `assumenosideeffects` seems too indirect for what you want to do given that it's about removing unused *methods*. (So the reason it can remove logging method calls is that `void` methods with no side effects are redundant.) It's probably overkill, but you might try doing something like defining `TAG` to be a static method instead of a field, like:  `private static final String TAG() { return getSimpleName(); }`. This will slow down debug builds, but ProGuard *should* be able to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.my.package.Logger { *; }
```

is bad indeed, because it includes all Object methods, such as `Object#wait()`. You probably don't want ProGuard to remove those invocations from your application. You should list your logging methods explicitly.

In general, to get rid of the invocation `getSimpleName`, it may help to specify

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.lang.Object {
    java.lang.String getSimpleName();
}
```

In this case, the field access isn't removed from the method though (with ProGuard 5.0). This is based on a number of internal rules, which have to take into account that accessing fields can have side-effects. This simple case should have been handled. I'll see how it can be improved.